# Travis CI Fail Jest testing for Timeout reason

Tags: node.js, timeout, travis-ci, yeoman, jestjs

The exact error message is :

```
Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout  
specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

At first, only Node.js 4 version build was failing.
After adding more test, all Node.js version builds were broken (4, 6, 7, 8).

I use Travis CI for my test and Jest (for a Yeoman generator).

You can check out the [job log](https://travis-ci.org/C0ZEN/generator-cozen-angular/jobs/319354261) error message if you want.

**Tried:**

Set a new timeout value.

```
let originalTimeout;

describe('generator-cozen-angular:sub-task', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        originalTimeout                  = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 30000;
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
    });

    it('do some stuff');
});
```

If you have an idea or a solution, you will save my day.
Thanks.

Comment: The probably needs more context of what tests are being run. Most likely your test isn't correctly executing and the async callback never runs.

Comment: Is it normal since local testing is totally fine ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found out the solution by reading the Jest documentation.

Since the errors are only in Travis CI, I assumed that their servers were just slower than my local one.

With that information, running :

```
jest --runInBand
```

Fixed my problems.

**EDIT 1:**

I encountered the problem one more time by addind more tests.
The other solution found is to change the Jest timeout.

```
jest.setTimeout(10000);
```

Where `10000` is milliseconds.
To add on top of the file just before the describe.

Comment: Another possible solution may be to set `--maxWorkers=2`. See https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5989